# Close popup when mouse leaves

Tags: wpf, popup

I have a popup window which is opened, and then within that popup the user can drag an item (from within the popup) which starts a DragDrop.DoDragDrop();

How can I have the popup automatically close when the users cursor leaves the Popup window?

I've tried a few options such as MouseEnter/Leave events and IsMouseOver properties, but none of these work as I believe the DragDrop initiates mouse capture.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
popup.Child.MouseLeave += (u, l) => popup.IsOpen = false;
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help because the DragDrop operation results in a mouse leave when as soon as the user starts the drag. I only want the popup to close when the cursor leaves the bounds of the popup window.